# Creating an IF - Else Statement in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, if-statement, razor

I am getting an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` in running my MVC Html Razor. I search on google on how to create an `IF-Else` in razor and found some good answer. But in my case I am getting an error.

My Code

```
<td  style="text-align: left" >
                    <div id="divEBSN">
                    @if (Model.RCEducationalBackground.School.SchooldName != null)
                    {
                       <span style="color: Red">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RCEducationalBackground.School.SchooldName)</span>    
                    }
                    else { 
                        <span style ="color:Red">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RCEducationalBackground.SchoolNameEducBG)</span>
                    }
                    </div>
                </td>
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more detail on this? as in your `model` and way you are passing your `model` from `controller` to `view`

Comment: Because either `RCEducationalBackground` or `School` is `null`

Comment: `SchooldName ` is not the object itself, its the property of your object. You are getting the error because School might be null or the RCEducationalBackground is null

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes my If statement is null that's why I create an if statement.

Comment: `@if (Model.RCEducationalBackground.School != null)`

Comment: @MidTwo I will try it. But I only want the SchoolName

Comment: If `Model` is `null` it wil throw the exception because you cannot get the `RCEducationalBackground` of `null`. If `RCEducationalBackground` is `null` you get the exception because you cannot get the `School` of `null` - ditto for the `SchooldName` property. You need to check all of them